# How can one enable SAML federation in the Cognito Hosted UI without advertising their customer list?

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, identity

I am building an enterprise app and federating signin using the Cognito Hosted UI solution, and people can sign up individually using any email, but they might also work for a company which has signed an enterprise deal with us and use SSO.

The desired workflow is one in which they input their signin email, then it is checked against our list of SAML Single Sign On providers, and if they match an enterprise client using SSO they are sent to the proper federation page; if they don't match any, they are taken to the general purpose login.

So far, I have successfully used the Hosted UI and the critical `idpIdentifier` parameter to create the desired behavior successfully. The following React code summarizes how this works:

```
    hostedUILogin() {
        const idpIdentifier = this.state.email.split("@")[1];

        let url = `https://${domain}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectSignIn}`;

        if (idpIdentifier) {
            url += `&idp_identifier=${idpIdentifier}`;
        }

        window.location.assign(url);

    }
```

This produces the desired effect. When somebody signs in with an email address that ends in "@corporatecustomer.com" they are taken to the SSO page for Corporation's federation. When somebody signs in with "@gmail.com", they are taken to the Cognito Hosted UI.

Unfortunately, the Hosted UI seems to be unable to help itself but to show off our customer list on the left-hand side.

[image: Screenshot]

I am unable to discover in the documentation or tutorials any way to use the Cognito Hosted UI without advertising all available SAML providers on the left hand side, thereby giving away our customer list.

I have tried taking away the IDP for this Hosted UI App in the App Client configuration, but then it no longer captures through the idp_identifier successfully.

Comment: I am now facing the exactly same problem. We’re you able to come up with a solution?

Comment: I stumbled upon this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-managing-saml-idp-naming.html

Answer (score 0):

If it helps to you, one of the solutions I found was to create a single User Pool per Corporate Customer

Answer (score 0):

You can create different App Client, and you can enable only identity provider on the first one, and native username/password on the other one.

For each App Client, you can dynamically change your AWS Config on the client side.

On our use case, SSO users may not have the same identity provider name on their email domains so we have "Login with SSO" button, which first handles kind of "Home Realm Discovery" by sending a request to backend with user's email and that endpoint returns the identity provider name belong to that user. Then the client initiates the federated sign in (or direct call to the hosted UI with identity provider parameter).